# Phonegap or native for a TV Guide app

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm planning to create a TV Guide app. The app has to interact with a server to get the data and display it in a timetable. The speed and UX are really important. Nothing flashy, I just want the page and state transitions to be very smooth and the assets/icons to look very good. Is it viable to use Phonegap for this app? I'm more proficient in HTML+CSS+javascript than Java/Obj-C but won't mind going native if it's the best way provide awesome UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the decision to use phonegap comes down to abilities, resources and performance needs. Phonegap will be slower than native just by it's very nature that it's another layer on top of native whereas native is optimized to be as fast as possible. Then the second question is your resources. If you only plan on releasing to one platform and have the ability to build native, that could make the most sense. On the other hand if you don't have the resources and want to build to multiple platforms quicker, phonegap will definitely fill that need.

For frameworks, there is sencha, jquery mobile, Dojo Mobile (I find that framework to be the most difficult to use) and Kendo UI (newest of the bunch but not really free either).

And another great template start is to use Mobile Boilerplate to understand the best practices for an hmtl5 starting page. 
http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

Comment: I understand that Phonegap will be a bit slower than native. My question is will the lag be noticeable when I display a complex table and during page/state transitions. Thanks for pointing me to mobile boilerplate.

Comment: There will be a lag, but it probably won't be noticeable enough to most users as long as the table isn't super complex. But even so, if you have a lot of data to show, caching and making async requests to load "pages" would be a better strategy then showing it all at once too.

Comment: Thanks, will try doing those things.

Answer (score 2):

You can totally do it with phonegap. I'd recommend using a javascript framework as well such as backbone.js for transitions and such.

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap just wrapps a native-app hull around a browser-application. This means: the phonegap-app must simulate a webbrowser and its javascript-engine. It does not convert your application into a real native app. This makes phonegap-apps slower than native apps.

I made bad experiences with an app that is scrolling through a long table of more than 1000 items, each of them holding five text-strings and two icons. Scrolling through the first 10 or 20 items was reasonable, but at item #50 it became really slow, and beyond item #100 scrolling was almost imposible.

So I wrote a native iPhone-App, and it scrolls at the end of the list as fast as at the beginning.

conclusio:

PhoneGap is fine for simple apps that need little resources. But when dealing with long lists or pages that are made of many different items, phonegap is considerable slower than a native app.

Answer (score 1):

if you use phonegap, it will be more easy to create the app for the  other platformes(android WP7 ...) 
but improving it will take you much more time.
because to have nice transitions and effects with phonegap , you wil need some libs and frameworks like (jquery mobile ,sencha touch ,dojo framwork)